# How to extract all words using regex which falls between specific pattern using Python

Tags: regex

```
df['text'][0] = 'beautiful place\nlocation: United States Of America\ntraveldate:'
```

I need to extract all words after 'location' and before the `\n` character.

I tried regex pattern in below code:

```
def Location(txt):
    txt1 = re.findall(r"(location:\s[A-Z]\w+)", txt)
    return txt1
df['Location'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x : Location(x))
```

Actual Output: `['location: United']`

Expected Output: `'United States Of America'`

Comment: See the [extracting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090826/3832970) that is much simpler than a [replacing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090214/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.replace` with a capture group:

```
df['Location'] = df['text'].str
    .replace(r'^.*\blocation:\s*([^\n]+).*$', r'\1', flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.extract`:

```py
df['Location'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'\blocation:\s*(.+)', expand=False)
```

The pattern matches

- `\b` -  a word boundary
- `location:` - a whole word `location` and a `:`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(.+)` - (Group 1, the `str.extract` return value) one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["beautiful place\nlocation: United States Of America\ntraveldate:"]})
>>> df['Location'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'\blocation:\s*(.+)', expand=False)
>>> df
                                                text                  Location
0  beautiful place\nlocation: United States Of Am...  United States Of America
```